# when i check dart version on cmd i got version 2.16.0(stable) but on flutter doctor i found 2.0.14

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  sqflite: ^2.0.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  bloc: ^8.0.2
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  conditional_builder_null_safety: ^0.0.6
  dio: ^4.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.0
```

I get this error:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.13.4

Because todo depends on webview_flutter >=2.0.14 which requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because todo depends on webview_flutter >=2.0.14 which requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current dart sdk version is 2.13.4, 2.0.14 is *webview_flutter* version, and in error message it asks you so dart sdk version is above 2.14.

Since one of the releases( do not remember which one :(, proof is [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#run-flutter-doctor) ) Dart is bundled with flutter sdk so if you installed dart on your system separately versions might mismatch because flutter uses bundled one and in shell you see system one. try upgrading flutter sdk constraints.

[image]